# Как вытянуть из JSON значение

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

Есть таблица с колонками CustomerID и Info.

Пример содержимого Info по пользователю 17:

```
[{"Key":"ErrorCode","Value":"16734}, {"Key":"DocumentNationality","Value":null},
{"Key":"DocumentAddress","Value":null} ]
```

Мне нужно создать таблицу с колонками CustomerID и ErrorCode. То есть в итоге по этому пользователю будет строка:

```
CustomerID      ErrorCode
   17             16734
```

Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

Comment: Если сервер версии 2016 и выше посмотрите в сторону функции openjson

Answer (score 1):

Была лишняя двойная кавычка рядом с 16734.
Я должен был удалить ее, чтобы сделать JSON правильным.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (CustomerID INT PRIMARY KEY, Info NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (CustomerID, Info) VALUES
(17, N'[{"Key":"ErrorCode","Value":16734}, {"Key":"DocumentNationality","Value":null}, {"Key":"DocumentAddress","Value":null} ]');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT t.CustomerID, [Key], [Value] AS ErrorCode
    FROM @tbl AS t
       CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.Info)
        WITH (   
                      Value   VARCHAR(200)   '$.Value',  
                      [Key]   VARCHAR(200)   '$.Key'
        )
)
SELECT CustomerID, ErrorCode
FROM rs
WHERE [Key] = 'ErrorCode';
```

> результат

```
+------------+-----------+
| CustomerID | ErrorCode |
+------------+-----------+
|         17 |     16734 |
+------------+-----------+
```